# react-hook-form check if a value is included in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I'm working with react-hook-form, and I have the following code

```
const array = ['foo', 'bar']

const Form = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitFunction)}>
        <input
          type="text"
          {...register("value", {
            required: true,
          })}
        />

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is there a way to check if a registered input value is included in the array?
Something like

```
array.includes(value)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you explain more about ur question?

Comment: I've edited the code, I want to check if an input value is inside an array, the same functionality as array.includes(value)

Comment: and you can't use just `.includes` for some reason?

Comment: i'm using react-hook-form, and the validations are slightly different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From offical doc:

> You can pass a callback function as the argument to validate, or you can pass an object of callback functions to validate all of them. This function will be executed on its own without depending on other validation rules included in the required attribute. Note: for object or array input data, it's recommended to use the validate function for validation as the other rules mos
> tly apply to string, string[], number and boolean data types.

```js
<input
  {...register("test", {
    validate: value => value === '1' || 'error message'  // JS only: <p>error message</p> TS only support string
  })}
/>
```

For the error message

```js
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("singleErrorInput", { required: "This is required." })} />
      <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="singleErrorInput" />
      
      <ErrorMessage
        errors={errors}
        name="singleErrorInput"
        render={({ message }) => <p>{message}</p>}
      />
      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

multi call backs

```
// object of callback functions
<input
  {...register("test1", {
    validate: {
      positive: v => parseInt(v) > 0,
      lessThanTen: v => parseInt(v) < 10,
      validateNumber: (_, values) =>
        !!(values.number1 + values.number2), 
      checkUrl: async () => await fetch(),
    }
  })}
/>
```

you can pass callback funcation in `validate`

Comment: if this answer your question. or tell me more i will edit my answer

Comment: than you! I'll check that!

Comment: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

Comment: It worked, thank you!
Two more questions, if I need to make many validations like this with their custom error messages, how can I do that? and how can i get the 'error message' that the validate callback returns? Thanks!

Comment: @Fernando I guess you could just set up a funcation out side the form and return whatever this validate take and then plug into the validate. oh i see what u mean, u mean many validations in a same input?

Comment: Exactly, many validations with different errors messages ins a same input

Comment: answer edited  for muti callback